# Retrieving a filtered list of stored procedures using t-sql

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to get a list of stored procedures in t-sql.  I am using the line:

```
exec sys.sp_stored_procedures;
```

I would like to filter the results back though, so I only get user created stored procedures.  I would like to filter out sp_*, dt_*, fn_*, xp_* and everything else that is a system stored procedure and no interest to me.  How can I manipulate the result set returned?

Using Sql Server 2008 express.

Solved!  Here is what I used:

```
SELECT name FROM sys.procedures
WHERE [type] = 'P'
AND name NOT LIKE 'sp_%'
AND name NOT LIKE 'dt_%'
ORDER BY name ASC;
```

Comment: The title of this question doesn't match the solution, could the title be edited to 'how to list stored procedures'?

Comment: I agree, the title was terrible.  I have updated it.

Comment: You can replace the 2nd and 3rd WHERE clause with  `is_ms_shipped = 0` for a more reliable list of user defined procedures.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Rather than using the Stored Procedure you can use the following views:

```
Select * From sys.procedures
Where [Type] = 'P'
```

or

```
Select * From Information_Schema.Routines
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'll put the full solution back into my question.

Answer (score 2):

Select items from the [sysobjects table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql) and use a where clause `type = 'P'` for stored procedures and filter on `name`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT [Routine_Name]
FROM   [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[ROUTINES]
WHERE  [ROUTINE_TYPE] = 'PROCEDURE'
```