# Copy Stored Procedures Names Only

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am being asked to collect all procedures' names that were used in one of our applications for migration purposes. To solve this, I could easily right click on each proc, copy the name and then add it to a doc. But since there could be so many procs and hence more room for errors, manual copy paste does not sound like the best solution here.

The question, is there -programmatically- a more intelligent alternative to accomplishing this task; taking into consideration that all procedures start with ***the same sub-string***?!

```
TST_DeleteCust
TST_AddCust
TST_UpdateCust
TST_Etc
TST_...
```

Comment: If you want to ask the server for procedure names: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522390/retrieving-a-filtered-list-of-stored-procedures-using-t-sql if you are asking how to extract them from a codebase that's an entirely different thing ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE SPECIFIC_NAME like '%TST_%' and ROUTINE_TYPE='PROCEDURE'
```

Comment: You should escape that underscore character or it will be treated as a single character wildcard in the LIKE.

Comment: @JoeStefanelli, both '%TST_%' and '%TST%' returned the same the result

Comment: You need `like 'TST[_]%'` for strings starting with `'TST+'`

Answer (score 0):

As we may not be sure about SPECIFIC_NAME, you can use below:

```
SELECT ROUTINE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE='PROCEDURE'
```